# How do I enter P4 triggers from standard input on Windows

Tags: triggers, cmd, perforce

I need to set the table to perforce triggers from the command line on Windows 8.

I am entering the following command and pressing "enter":

C:\Program Files\Perforce>p4 -H localhost -p 1666 -u Administrator -P ****** triggers -i

Text cursor moves to a new line as if it awaits the trigger lines. Good so far. I input triggers one by one and when I am done, I have no idea how to tell p4.exe to "flush" my input and save it. What is the correct way of setting triggers in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -i option allows you to "*Read the trigger **table** from standard input without invoking the editor*".  The keyword here is *table*.  You have to enter the entire trigger table, in its proper format, not just your triggers.  The trigger table starts with a line that contains the following...

```
Triggers:
```

...followed by *"a list of triggers; one per line. Each trigger line must be indented with spaces or tabs in the form. Each line has four elements..."*

So, entering the trigger table from the command line might look something like this (I'm just entering a single trigger in this example):

```
C:\>p4 triggers -i
Triggers:
        example change-submit //depot/... "cmd %changelist%"

C:\>
```

The sequence is...

"Triggers:" <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> [trigger line] <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> [trigger line] <kbd>Enter</kbd>...

...until you are done entering all of your triggers.  When you are done, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to "flush" your input and save it.

Answer (score 3):

Omit the -i and things are much easier: Perforce will bring up your P4EDITOR, which is Notepad by default I think, and you can edit your trigger table in Notepad and then save it.